# Android - image transition velcome screen

Tags: android, image, transition

I am creating turistic app and I have made some significant research about design. Now I want to try in Android display background image in main menu. Do you know, is it possible to have there image, which changes periodically with some transition effects? On background there should be turistic pictures, which will be changing time to time. Is it possible with Android? I am asking here, cos I wasn't able to find solution up to now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to use [this](http://abhi-java.blogspot.com/2010/07/android-image-transition-for-animation.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not! you can apply a thread which will change the background image from time to time, and if you are going to deploy it not ICS you can have the transition effect also.